# Group Mulitple Rows into 1 email in mail merge

Tags: email, ms-word, office365, ms-office, mailmerge

I have to send an email out to all the team managers of my company providing the individual stats for each member of their team. Unfortunately I am not very well acquainted with mail merge and have been running into multiple knowledge gaps. I was hoping somebody here could help me understand how I can do this. If the sample data looks like this:

| TM Email | Employee Name | Call Goal | Actual | % Goal Met | # of Audits | Accuracy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email1@fakeemail.com | John Doe | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email1@fakeemail.com | Jane Doe | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email1@fakeemail.com | Eric Stultz | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email1@fakeemail.com | Christian Noname | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email1@fakeemail.com | Fakename Mcgee | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email1@fakeemail.com | senor chapo | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email2@mail.com | Duck Werthington | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email2@mail.com | Myster Eeman | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email2@mail.com | Ion No | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email2@mail.com | No Idea | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |
| email2@mail.com | Mail Man | 100 | 50 | 50% | 4 | 92% |

> Assume that there are over 2 dozen Team Managers with varying team sizes. and the email will be sent in the same format as listed above. How would I go about this, I don't even know where to begin. Please help.

Comment: One option would be to use a DATABASE field in a normal ‘letter’ mailmerge main document and a macro to drive the process. An outline of this approach can be found at:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/many-to-one-email-merge-using-tables/8bce1798-fbe8-41f9-a121-1996c14dca5d

Comment: See also, my replies at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us...g-tables/8bce1798-fbe8-41f9-a121-1996c14dca5d & https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us...gle-page/4edb4654-27e0-47d2-bd5f-8642e46fa103